# How to add labels with categorical variables to a line chart in python?

Tags: python, graph, label, color-coding

I have a dataset containing UAV data. I want to create a graph showing the altitude of the drone and the flight phase. On that graph I want to label the phases of flight (so take off, cruising, landing, etc). I can easily make the graph showing altitude, but I have no idea how to add in the flight phases. Could anyone help? I would like the flight phase to be visible on the altitude line graph. This could be either through colour coding, or through labels which signify when the flight phase starts/changes.

My data looks something like this (edited to add more data for clarification):

| time (s) | phase | altitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | take off | 10 |
| 2 | take off | 20 |
| 50 | cruise | 500 |
| 51 | cruise | 500 |
| 200 | landing | 20 |
| 201 | landing | 10 |
| 202 | take off | 10 |
| 203 | take off | 20 |
| 250 | cruise | 500 |
| 251 | cruise | 500 |
| 300 | landing | 20 |
| 301 | landing | 10 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": [i for i in range(1, 201)],
    "phase": ["take off"]*50 + ["cruise"]*100 + ["landing"]*50,
    "altitude": [i*10 for i in range(1, 51)] + [500]*101 + [i*10 for i in range(49, 0, -1)],
})
data
```

**Output:**

```
time    phase   altitude
0   1   take off    10
1   2   take off    20
2   3   take off    30
3   4   take off    40
4   5   take off    50
... ... ... ...
195 196 landing     50
196 197 landing     40
197 198 landing     30
198 199 landing     20
199 200 landing     10
```

You can try this:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x="time", y="altitude", data=data, hue="phase")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This does look like what I want, but when I try to execute it with my data it's clearly doing it wrong. The "hue" argument seems to add extra lines and data all over the graph and I have no idea where this is coming from. It looks like seaborn thinks some of the categories overlap, but in the actual dataset none of them overlap. Some parts of the graph have 4 coloured lines overlapping, which can't be right. Many of these lines are perfectly straight, making me think it's not even graphing the altitude data.

Comment: I think I know the issue. These variables appear several times in the dataset. So the dataset contains data showing a take off, cruise, and landing happening several times in the same dataset. Seaborn seems to link up every time these appear on the graph which results in lots of straight lines across the graph that do not really make sense. Instead of having a take off at 1 second and another at 500 seconds, the end of the first take off and the beginning of the second one are linked by a coloured line on the graph. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't fully understand exactly what your data looks like.

Comment: My graph works when there is a record with phase and height for each second.

Comment: Take the example you gave, double it and concat, you will see what I mean. If there are more than one example of "phase" (for example, a dataset containing several take offs and landings) the hue lines do not make sense. The end of the first take off will be linked by a coloured line to the beginning of the next take off.